# Get list of all form objects by form name C#

Tags: c#, winforms

String `ext` contains the form name, I want to put this new form name instead of `this` in GetAll function.

```cs
string ext = checkedListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString().Substring(0, checkedListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString().LastIndexOf("/"));

var c = GetAll(this, typeof(Button));

public IEnumerable<Control> GetAll(Control control, Type type)
{
    var controls = control.Controls.Cast<Control>();

    return controls.SelectMany(ctrl => GetAll(ctrl, type))
                   .Concat(controls)
                   .Where(c => c.GetType() == type);
}
```

Comment: You cannot do this reliably.  You are describing a solution without describing the problem this is supposed to solve, not a good idea.

Comment: I want to use it in User security management form to list all selected form buttons.

Comment: I can help you if you specify what you mean by form **Name**. Is it the Name property of the form or the form type Name? Also are those forms are located in a single namespace?

Comment: Thanks, ymdred16 what I want to pass the form to the GetAll function, I have CheckedListBox contains a list of all My project forms, when the user selects one  "variable ext get the name of the selected form" I want to show all buttons in that selected form.

Answer (score 0):

if form is open, then it can be found in [Application.OpenForms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.openforms) collection:

```
var form = Application.OpenForms.Cast<Form>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == ext);
var buttons = GetAll(form, typeof(Button));
```

Comment: Not Opened ... I want to use it in User security management form to list all selected form buttons.